# Error querying Hive tables when using 'Order by' or 'Group by'

Tags: java, hive

I recently installed DBvisualizier to query Hive tables. I installed it on my Mac and downloaded/installed the jdbc jar files for Hive from this website: https://s3.amazonaws.com/public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/hive-jdbc4/1.0.42.1054/Simba_HiveJDBC41_1.0.42.1054.zip

When I connected to our DB and test the queries. A simple select would work:

```
select *

from table_name

limit 10
```

But when I added 'order by' or 'group by':

```
select *

from table_name

order by rollingtime

limit 10
```

I got the following error which I have no clue why. Did anyone have similar error and know how to fix this?

```
09:56:17 START Executing for: 'NewDev' [Hive], Database: Hive, Schema: sdc

09:56:17 FAILED [SELECT - 0 rows, 0.504 secs] [Code: 500051, SQL State: HY000] [Simba][HiveJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 2, SQL state: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1516123265840_0008_8_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1516123265840_0008_8_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tez.runtime.library.api.TezRuntimeConfiguration

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:107)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:186)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:188)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:172)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)

 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)

 at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.daemon.impl.StatsRecordingThreadPool$WrappedCallable.call(StatsRecordingThreadPool.java:110)

 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

, errorMessage=Cannot recover from this error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tez.runtime.library.api.TezRuntimeConfiguration

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.library.output.OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.start(OrderedPartitionedKVOutput.java:107)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:186)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:188)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:172)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)

 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)

 at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)

 at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)

 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.llap.daemon.impl.StatsRecordingThreadPool$WrappedCallable.call(StatsRecordingThreadPool.java:110)

 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:1, Vertex vertex_1516123265840_0008_8_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1516123265840_0008_8_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:1, Vertex vertex_1516123265840_0008_8_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1, Query: select *

from nomura_qa_mblock_capacity_stage

order by rollingtime

limit 10.  

select *

from nomura_qa_mblock_capacity_stage

order by rollingtime

limit 10;

09:56:17 END Execution 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.504/0.000 secs [0 successful, 1 errors]
```

Comment: Is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes caused by an inability to write to the configured or hardcoded `.staging` directory usually because of an incorrect path or invalid permissions.

The mapreduce exec engine is more verbose than the tez engine in helping to identify the culprit which you can choose by running this query in your Hive shell:

```
SET hive.execution.engine=mr
```

You may then be able to see the following error:

> Permission denied: user=dbuser, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user/dbuser/.staging":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

In this case, the "dbuser" staging directory is specified to a non-existent path, it should be `/home/dbuser/.staging`

At runtime, before executing any queries that perform actions which would need to be staged (sort, order, group, distribute, etc) along with setting the exec engine to `mr` as previously shown, you would set the staging path to a valid parent directory such as your user's home dir by running the following query:

```
SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir=/home/dbuser/.staging
```

Depending on version and environment, if that directive doesn't work, you can try

```
SET hive.exec.stagingdir=/home/dbuser/.staging
```

Of course, change "dbuser" to your actual home directory (or any other to which you have read/write access). The .staging directory, assuming write access by the user running the query will automatically be created.

More info at http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Default+mapred+Parameters